# Question about particular mathematical manipulation in Tong's Statistical Physics notes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

In page two of the Classical Gases section of David Tong's [notes on Statistical Physics](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys.html), he is deriving the partition function for a classical particle from the quantum particle.

[image]

I'm a bit confused about how he goes from the first line to the second. How is he able to push the $\exp(-\beta V(\hat{q}))$ term through the $\exp(-\beta \hat{p}^2/2m$) term and the bra?

Comment: He's not "push[ing]" it "through the $\exp(-\beta \hat p^2/2m)$ term. He's letting it act on the $|q\rangle$ ket and then is is just a regular function of $q$ so it commutes with everything.

Comment: Oh, so the $\exp(-\beta V(q))$ is kind of an eigenvalue?

Comment: For any function $f(\hat q)$ of the operator $\hat q$, you should be able to show that $f(\hat q)|q\rangle = |q\rangle f(q)$. Yes, the eigenvalues of the operator $f(\hat q)$ are the $f(q)$.

Comment: And please use MathJax in the future. Don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: @hft I've told OP already as a comment under their last question...

Comment: @TobiasFünke "What we've got here is a failure to communicate. Some [OPs] you just can't reach."

Comment: Got it, thank you so much! My mistake, it has been awhile since I've posted on here, I'll transcribe it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exponent is acting on q state... Expand the exponent term and (1+ $\beta$V + $(\beta*V)^2/2 !+……$ acts on |q⟩  and you already know V(q) operator acting on|q⟩ will give the V(q).... That's it!